# Как правильно закодировать JSON на JS чтобы принять на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Есть информация об id определённой записи на сайте которую я в последствии пытаюсь передать в php

```
fetch('deleteNote.php', 
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({"id" : notes[note].id})
            })
```

Но на PHP при попытке разобрать этот JSON запись id становится ключом для пустой записи.
То есть после

```
json_encode($_POST)
```

Вижу

```
{"{"id":"1"}":""}
```

И как оттуда правильно вытащить этот ID, или как его правильно переслать не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А `json_decode($_POST)` что выдает? ;)

Comment: + Content-Type для json лучше `application/json`, а не  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @RTK подозреваю у него нет цели именно json данные отправить. он просто хочет получить `$_POST['id']`. поэтому в целом контент-тайп нормальный.

Comment: json_decode($_POST) применить нельзя т.к. он принимает строковый аргумент

Comment: Вы всё-таки определитесь `JSON` или `x-www-form-urlencoded`. А то у вас заголовках одно, а в теле запроса другое и PHP офигевает

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужно просто `body: new URLSearchParams({id: notes[note].id})` и получать на сервере через `$_POST['id']`

Comment: После этих изменений $_POST['id'] выдает просто поле, а json_encode($_POST) выдает - []

Comment: Ну так а какой результат вы хотите вместо «просто поля»?

Comment: Тот id который я передаю с JS